# How should I design my table in Firebase Realtime Database if I want to display a table like this in HTML?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, html-table, firebase-console

[Sample table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTkXp.png)

I need each user to select the course name and automatically display the attendance marks of the students in different dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to structure it like this:

```
courses/
  {courseId}/
    attendance/
      {studentId}/
        {date}: {bool}
```

This assumes you have all courses listed somewhere, it's not a good idea to use this as a source for that dropdown that only actually needs course's title and/or id.

Once the user selects a course, you use that id to fetch the course's attendance data at `courses/{selectedId}/attendance`. Then parse the values for each student and date appropriately.

You can add other course related info like this `courses/{courseId}/title: "Firebase"`.